# @HTML.Drop Down List and displaying databound information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently trying to post a set of missing SQL query reports to a dropdown selection on my web page.

I believe my Model is correct, but there's some issue with it recognizing any list as part of the @HTML.DropDown even though my  controller has appropriate syntax. Thus, the application crashes before rendering the webpage.  I hope this is an easy fix.

Here's my controller code for the function to be called:

```
public ActionResult FindDatMissingQuery()
        {
            HomeModel H = new HomeModel();
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.DataSource = H.MissingQueryResults();
            ddl.DataBind();
            ViewData["MissingChem"] = ddl;

            return View();
        }
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FindDatMissingQuery","Home")){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Missing Chemistry Report</legend>
    <br />

@Html.DropDownList("MissingChemistryReports", ViewData["MissingChem"] as SelectList)

</fieldset>

}
```

My Model function:

```
 public List<string> MissingQueryResults()
        {
            //HomeModel Tolerances = new HomeModel();
            List<String> nameList = new List<String>();

            SqlCommand missingQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT heatname FROM dbo.chemistrytable WHERE heatname NOT IN (SELECT heatname FROM dbo.chemistrytable WHERE sampletype = 'AVE') AND analysistime bewteen Dateadd(day, -1, Current_Timestamp) and Current_Timestamp AND heatname LIKE '[a,b,c,d]%' Order by heatname'");// + heatName + "'");
            SqlCommand mainquery = new SqlCommand("SELECT analysisvalue.analysisid, heatname, analysistime, sampletype, grade, productid, element, value FROM dbo.AnalysisValue INNER JOIN dbo.ChemistryAnalysis ON dbo.AnalysisValue.AnalysisID = dbo.ChemistryAnalysis.AnalysisID Where heatname = '" + heatName + "' Order By analysisvalue.analysisid Asc, element");

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection))
            {
                missingQuery.CommandTimeout = 20000;
                conn.Open();
                missingQuery.Connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
                missingQuery.Connection.Open();

                using (var reader = missingQuery.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            nameList.Add(reader[i].ToString().Trim());

                        }

                    }
                }return nameList;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing what `HomeModel.MissingQueryResults` looks like. On a more general note, the `MissingChemistryReports` and `MissingChem` should both be in your View Model because they are data for your View. Your View Models should not just be directly mapped to database entities.

Comment: I apologize Ant P, I will edit the question now.

Comment: You're creating a DropDownList object, which is probably a Windows forms DropDownList, or an asp.net DropDownList, not an MVC helper.  You are then trying to cast that DropDownList to a SelectList, which it is not.  You need to create a SelectList, not a DropDownList in your controller.

Comment: @Mystere Man, Can I cast the H.MissingQueryResults to a SelectList all the same?

Comment: Did changes, receive same error: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MissingChemistryReports'."

Comment: @user1414048 - No, H.MissingQueryResults is not a SelectList either.  You can only cast something to a SelectList if it *IS* a SelectList, that is, you created a new SelectList(), which you are not doing.

Comment: @user1414048 That's because you shoved a `DropDownList` into that ViewData item, and are trying to retrieve it as a `SelectList`. There's not a direct cast for that on the `SelectList` class.

Comment: These 2 lines in the controller confuse me: `HomeModel H = new HomeModel();` ...  `return View();` You aren't actually binding your Model to your View this way. I realize you are shoving the sql results into that ViewData item, but its a lot easier to just have a ViewModel that holds everything you need, and return that bound to your View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I use dropdown lists in my example:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ActiveErrors", ListHelpers.PartsActive())


public static List<SelectListItem> PartsActive()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "Y" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "A" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "N" });
    return list;
}
```

**OR WITH A MODEL PROPERTY**

Controller:

```
ViewBag.RunTypeID = new SelectList(db.RunType, "ID", "RunTypeName").OrderBy(l => l.Text);
```

View:

```
<span class="rightContent">
        @Html.DropDownList("RunTypeID", String.Empty)
    </span>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how this going to help.  The db.RunType parameter for selectList needs some explaining.

Comment: db.runtype is the datasource for intance my entity table, this fetched the data. ID is the value for the row and runtypename is the key/table column which gets displayed into the dropdown list.

Comment: So how could this work with the MissingQueryResults function, which is returning a List?  There's also the issue that due to client restrictions,  I can't use entity framework.

Comment: ok first is it necessary to return a view to populate this dropdown. cant you just have a helper method returning data for your dropdown?

Comment: try this in your view    @Html.DropDownList("MissingChem", MissingQueryResults())

Comment: Thanks tam tam, I've figured it out.  You helped!